# C++ - Filling multidimensional vector with data from file with delimiters

Tags: c++, readfile

I need to fill my multidimensional vector with data from file with delimiter, so I do somethink like this:

```
ifstream file;
vector < vector<string> > stockVector;
vector<string> rowVector;

file.open( fileLocation(), std::ios::in | std::ios::out );

if ( !file.good() )
    return false;

string data;
while ( getline( file, data, ';' ) ) {
    for( int i = 0; i < 20; i++ ) {
        rowVector.push_back(data);
    }

    stockVector.push_back( rowVector );
}
```

But I'm getting `1` everywhere. What is bad?
Here is my file:

```
1;Guerra;36;0.95;
2;Rivas;14;3.20;
3;Petty;30;7.81;
4;Gallagher;65;8.00;
5;Nguyen;76;1.99;
6;Wooten;57;0.97;
7;Guerra;53;7.25;
8;Norman;6;5.82;
9;Dyer;72;8.69;
10;Martin;67;4.73;
11;Delgado;73;4.60;
12;Velasquez;87;1.76;
13;Crawford;95;0.66;
14;Houston;9;7.78;
15;Shaffer;85;4.40;
16;Hoover;99;0.81;
17;Webb;97;8.02;
18;Gonzales;22;1.78;
19;Gross;17;4.00;
20;Bridges;93;8.08;
```

Comment: Debug your program. You are reading `data` and add same value 20 time

Comment: What is bad is 1) You read a single word delimited by ';', then have a loop that puts 20 copies of it into a vector, because a computer does exactly what you tell it to do, instead of what you want it to do, 2) Reading a single word delimited by a ';' will, eventually, read a word containing a newline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few mistakes here, including a subtle one.

1) You need two `getline`'s here: one to read a (surprise) line from a file until `\n`, and another one to extract tokens out of the line read.

2) The second `getline` needs to have a delimiter of `;`.

3) Your two loops contradict each other. The `while` loop reads (incorrectly!) token by token from the file, and the other loop adds the very same token 20 times.

4) (The subtle error) You don't reset `rowVector` for every line in a file.

5) Hardcoding `20` is a bad idea, better let `getline` find the end of the file and string for you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::ifstream file;
    std::vector < std::vector<std::string> > stockVector;

    file.open( argv[1], std::ios::in | std::ios::out );

    if ( !file.good() )
        return false;

    for ( std::string data; getline(file, data); ) {
        std::istringstream linestr(data);
        std::vector<std::string> rowVector;
        for( std::string token; std::getline(linestr, token, ';'); ) {
            rowVector.push_back(token);
        }
        stockVector.push_back( rowVector );
    }

    for (const auto& v: stockVector ) {
        std::copy(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "));
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

See for reference:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator

Comment: Thanks, I'll read :)